# Namespace is no recognised while used inline. But mentioned at the top with using keyword , it works

Tags: c#

I am referring to an internal project. My current project uses reference of that project. My current project namespace is `currentProjOne.currentProjTwo.currentProjThree`. and the project which i am referring is namespace is `referredOne.referredTwo.referredThree`.

In my current project when i add referrend project on top of .cs page with using keywords like `using referredOne.referredTwo.referredThree`, All classess of that method are recognised by compiler.

But when i refer class as `referredOne.referredTwo.referredThree.class`  it throws compile time error of missing assembly.

let me put some point .
i have referred correct dll to the project
i have only one dll for that project
both the project are class liabrary and .net framework pointing to .net4 (not .net4 client profile).

I am clueless why this is happening. Please help.

Comment: Maybe your class in `referredThree` has the same name as one in `currentProjectThree` so when you use `using` it is not actually referencing the one you think it is, which is why it works.

Comment: Check namespaces of all classes in your referenced project and re-add the reference in your current project.

Comment: Please show the **actual** code. The word `class` is a keyword in C# so from your vague example it's unclear what actually could be the problem.

Comment: Thanks Gabe for quick comment. Name of that class is unique. There is no issue with name conflict.

Comment: Vivek i did as u mentioned. But error still exist. Thanks for comment

Comment: Ondrej , i know class is keyword. thats example word i used. BTW, I cannot share code due to privacy issue.